# Root cronjobs not running

Tags: ubuntu, cron

This is driving me nuts! I cannot have the job in the root crontab to run. This is what I have in the crontab:

```
5 * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /root/turf/recevoir_les_cotes.py
1 * * * * date >> /root/date.log
```

First it wasn't working I added a second line then it worked once. After I removed the second line it stopped working again. An now, even with the second line added it does not.

I edit the contrab with this command : `crontab -e -u root`
then I restart the cron: `service cron restart`

I am running Ununtu 18.04.6 LTS (Bionic Beaver)

Comment: now, it's kind of unlikely that you have spooky effects from the second line, so let's focus on the first. What *exactly* does happen if you manually, and importantly, as root, run `/usr/bin/python3 /root/turf/recevoir_les_cotes.py`?

Comment: it is running just fine when running manually /usr/bin/python3 /root/turf/recevoir_les_cotes.py as root

Comment: How do you know it's not working? What do you expect? Does the journal show any errors?

Comment: @ArièsPinoteau that's not the level of "*exact*" I was hoping for. What does it *do*, actually?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get the question. It retrieves some json files online, convert them to CSV and write them to a text file. But it is fine now I found my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys, I'm a real noob, new to cron. I was running perfectly as asked, every hour at five. I was thinking it would run every 5 minutes. Now I've replaced it with */5 * * * * !

Sorry for taking your time and attention for nothing. I will RTFM more carefully next time!